# Parsing a JSON in dataframe column in order of occurence

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where there is a column containing a JSON like -

```
Player ID               Response
    1                 [{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-3', 'content': 'Networking'}, {'id': '1-5', 'content': 'Opportunity'}]
    2                 [{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}]
    3                 [{'id': '1-3', 'content': 'Networking'}, {'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-2', 'content': 'Excuse'}]
    4                 [{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-6', 'content': 'Gain'}, {'id': '1-1', 'content': 'Different'}]
```

where the `Response` column contains 1-3 entities in an order. I need to re-order this column into something like -

```
  ID              Score     InResponse 
  1-1                1          1
  1-2                1          1
  1-3                5          2
  1-4               11          4 
  1-5                1          1
  1-6                2          1
```

where, if an ID is 1st in order, it gets 3 points, 2 pts if its second and 1 pt if its 3rd in order. So, for example, 1-4 is 1st in 3 responses and 2nd in one, so, `3x3 + 1x2 = 11 pts`. And `InResponse` means how many occurrences of that ID in the dataframe.

I tried

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.Q1.to_dict())
```

but for some reason it gives me unexpected results. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it something like this -

```
dict_response = {'1-1':0, '1-2':0, '1-3':0, '1-4':0, '1-5':0, '1-6':0, '1-7':0}
dict_occurrence = {'1-1':0, '1-2':0, '1-3':0, '1-4':0, '1-5':0, '1-6':0, '1-7':0}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dict_temp = json.loads(row['Response'].replace("'", '"'))
    dict_response[list(dict_temp[0].values())[0]] += 3
    dict_occurrence[list(dict_temp[0].values())[0]] += 1
    if len(dict_temp) > 1:
        dict_response[list(dict_temp[1].values())[0]] += 2
        dict_occurrence[list(dict_temp[1].values())[0]] += 1
    if len(dict_temp) > 2:
        dict_response[list(dict_temp[2].values())[0]] += 1
        dict_response[list(dict_temp[2].values())[0]] += 1

df_q1_responses = pd.DataFrame()
df_q1_responses['ID'] = dict_response.keys()
df_q1_responses['Points'] = df_q1_responses['ID'].map(dict_response)
df_q1_responses['Responses'] = df_q1_responses['ID'].map(dict_occurrence)
df_q1_responses
```

But I don't particularly like my solution that much. Please let me know if you have any improvements or alternate solutions!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is by applying a function on your data frame that appends whatever metadata you need to add to each JSON element, then group the rows back separately into a data frame then apply grouping, for example in python3.

```
# import data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Player ID', 'Response'], 
                  data=[
                     [1,[{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-3', 'content': 'Networking'}, {'id': '1-5', 'content': 'Opportunity'}]],
                     [2, [{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}]],
                     [3, [{'id': '1-3', 'content': 'Networking'}, {'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-2', 'content': 'Excuse'}]],
                     [4, [{'id': '1-4', 'content': 'Develop'}, {'id': '1-6', 'content': 'Gain'}, {'id': '1-1', 'content': 'Different'}]]])


arr = []
def insert_metadata(row):
    i=0
    for item in row:
        item['score'] = 3-i 
        item['In Response'] = 1
        i+=1
        arr.append(item)
    return row

df['Response'].apply(insert_metadata)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
final_df.groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
```